# User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, pgadmin

I have added two new columns 1.gender, 2.pinCode in PostgreSQL auth_user table and now I trying to post data in the table through Sign Up form to create a new user

Please let me know how to fix this issue, I'm stuck at this from last few days.

error - User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def login(request):
    pass

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstName = request.POST['firstName']
        lastName = request.POST['lastName']
        mobileNum = request.POST['mobileNum']
        emailID = request.POST['emailID']
        passFld1 = request.POST['passFld1']
        passFld2 = request.POST['passFld2']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        pinCode = request.POST['pinCode']

        myUser = User.objects.create_user(username=mobileNum, password=passFld1, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=emailID, gender=gender, pinCode=pinCode)
        myUser.save()
        print('User Created Successfully')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Not Allowed')
    # return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name="login"),
    path('signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
]
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="signup" id="signUpForm" class="login100-form validate-form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="login-title mb-5">Create an Account</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Name">
                <input class="input100 text-capitalize" onkeypress="return isAlphabet(event)" type="text" maxlength="15" name="firstName" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="First Name"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Name">
                <input class="input100 text-capitalize" onkeypress="return isAlphabet(event)" type="text" maxlength="15" name="lastName" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Last Name"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Mobile">
                <input class="input100" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onchange="isMobileNumber(this,'Invalid Mobile Number');" type="text" maxlength="10" name="mobileNum" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Mobile Number"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Email">
                <input class="input100" type="email" maxlength="30" name="emailID" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Email"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Password">
                <input class="input100" type="password" maxlength="20" name="passFld1" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid Password">
                <input class="input100" type="password" maxlength="20" name="passFld2" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="input100" required name="gender" id="gender">
                <option value="Hidden" hidden selected disabled>Hidden</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Others">Others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wrap-input100" data-validate="Invalid PIN Code">
                <input class="input100" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" type="text" maxlength="6" name="pinCode" required>
                <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="PIN Code"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn w-50">
            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <button type="submit" id="signUpSubmit" class="login100-form-btn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-info">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="newAccount mt-5">
        Already have an account? <span id="LogInBtn">Login</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Error**

````
TypeError at /signup
User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _init_, line 500
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Vipin\\Desktop\\Modifyz',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Vipin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 22 Aug 2020 07:19:28 +0000
```[enter image description here][1]



**Error Screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/soz0s.png
````

Comment: Can you please display model here as well?

Comment: @Vivek Papnai  Are you only add `gender and pinCode` field through direct to `PostgreSQL` ?? Is add in your `models.py` file ??

Comment: @IkramKhanNiazi  I have added models.py in the question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are importing `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, we can be 100 % sure that the model does not have a field named `gender`.

You can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) which fields are available and gender is not one of them. If you'd like to add a gender field to your `User` model, then you need to customize this model. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) is the documentation describing different approaches.

Generally it is smart to customize it when you start a new project. The documentation linked above gives and example how do to this.

1. Create custom model in one of your apps `models.py`

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    class User(AbstractUser):
        pass
   ```
2. Override AUTH_USER_MODEL in `settings.py`

   ```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
   ```
3. Register the model in app's `admin.py`

   ```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
    from .models import User

    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
   ```